# What if the luminosity of Sunlight increased by 10%

Tags: atmospheric-science, sun, estimation, biology, climate-science

If the luminosity of sunlight increased by 10%, would people be able to survive outside? Would such brightness of light be very harmful to them, for exemple as much as the Mercury Vapour Lamp without any protection  from UV light? I omit the temperature issue, I mean radiation itself, because I'm curious whether man (or bacteria) could survive if he went outside completely naked?

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a physics question to me, as you're concerned about the biological impacts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the survivability of life due to hypothetical changes in the environment which is more [biology.se] than physics.

Comment: Just wait a couple billion years and you can find out the hard way as star grow slowly brighter over the course of their dwell on the main sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the temperature issue is likely a mistake, since it would have big effects on Earth's temperature. The global temperature is roughly proportional to the fourth root of the luminosity, so it would increase by 2% - from 287 to about 294 degrees K (14 to 21 C), a pretty big shift.

The direct effect of 10% more sunlight is not radically different than going from high latitude regions to lower latitudes. A clear equatorial noon can reach 1000 W/m$^2$, while up here in the UK at most we can hope for is maybe 400 W/m$^2$ - 2.5 times less. So in much of the world the brighter sunlight would just make things more tropical and increase the risk of sunburn. Even on the equator I doubt many organisms are close to their UV limits, so the effects would be limited.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, it’d be better to include in your answer that the temperatures are in Kelvin as it’d be absurd to those who don’t know if an increase from 14 to 21 degrees is 2%.

Comment: @TausifHossain - Good point, fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Solar irradiance at ground level varies widely with latitude. The regions with highest irradiation are uninhabitable as they are now, without technical solutions. Thus the answer is that a larger fraction of the Earth will be uninhabitable. The effect will be more dramatic  if climate impact is taken into account. Note that if we model Earth as a black body a 10% increase in irradiation leads to a 7.5° [correction] temperature increase. Thus is a large figure but perhaps less than expected.